# Comparing array with non array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried to compare a value to another value in an array. However, the message only displays `exits in array 2`even when I have two different values (one is 10, the other values from the array are 4 and 6)

```
if (in_array($post,$orderP)==0){
    echo ' exists in array2';
}else{
    echo 'does not exists in array2';
}

echo $post; //gives a value of 10
echo var_dump ($orderP);
```

gives a value of

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["post_ID"]=> string(1) "4" 
                            [0]=> string(1) "4" 
                          } 
            [1]=> array(2) { ["post_ID"]=> string(1) "6" 
                             [0]=> string(1) "6" 
                            } 
        }
```

Comment: in_array itself will false or true so no need to check it with ==0 just if(in_array($post, $orderP)){echo 'exists';} is enough

Comment: @vSugumar ok, I tried to remove the == 0 and apparently it stills display does not exist even though I have a matching value of 4 and array(4)

Comment: check my below answer and tell me if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think in_array will check recursively,,, there may better code.. but my solution is..

```
$bool = false;
foreach($orderP as $order){

  if (in_array($post,$order)){
     echo ' exists in array2';
     $bool=true;
     return;
  }
}

if(!$bool){

    echo 'does not exists in array2';

}
```

Comment: thanks, it helped me. Both yours and the code above :)

Answer (score 1):

You have multidimensional array, so try something like this

```
$ids = array_column($orderP, 'post_ID');

if (in_array($post,$ids)){
            echo ' exists in array2';
            }
else{
            echo 'does not exists in array2';
            }
```